# JIRA: pair old/new IssueKey after changing project

Tags: jira

we used to have three different JIRA projects, and merged them all into one new project, resulting in new IssueKeys for all issues involved.
Unfortunately, test automation uses the IssueKey to update the issue about test results (via SQL INSERT statement), and I try to avoid updating the list of IssueKeys in the suite.

I can think of two ways:

- Addressing the issues by the old IssueKey. This seems to work in JIRA JQl search (issuekey=*ISSUE-OLD* finds the same issue as issuekey=*ISSUE-NEW* ), but not for the SQL INSERT statement.
- Getting a list of pairs old-new IssueKey. For example, in JIRA under "activity" and "all", I can see entries that log the changes. Exporting tose worklogs might be a great help, but there might be other ways.

Thanks in advance,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're updating a test management db, not the Jira db (which would not be good)

You might also be interested in the moved_issue_key table which is where Jira stores the previous issue keys (e.g. ABC-123) and maps them to an issue id (the id in the jiraissue table)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the curl api:

```
curl -D- -u user:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://url.com/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-OLD
```

The response will contain the key value as `ISSUE-NEW`  with other details.